# Power BI and Azure Web App diagnostic logs

Tags: azure, powerbi, azure-diagnostics, powerbi-embedded

I have enabled Diagnostic logs for Azure Web App and VMs. 
How can I view Azure Diagnostic logs in Power BI Dashboard?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Power BI Embedded does not integrate with Azure diagnostic logs.  If you are experiencing an issuing using Power BI Embedded please post your question and I would be happy to help.

Comment: I have enabled azure diagnostics logs for our ARM VMs and web apps. I want to analyses these logs using a dashboard, which can show good graph and easy to understand.

Comment: Thanks Wallace, if POwer BI doesn't integrate with azure diagnostics logs then could you suggest me any other simple tools which provide a good dash board analysis .

Comment: Are the logs stored in Azure table/blob storage?  If that is the case then you can use Power BI to visualize your data.

Answer (score 0):

You can export you query to powerBI desktop and from there import to a dashboard.  I have not found a way to do it directly yet.